# Vk парсинг изображения

Tags: php, json, вконтакте, vkontakte-api, парсер

С помощью

```
$wall = file_get_contents("http://api.vk.com/method/wall.get?v=5.3&domain=arkaim.world&count=5"); // Отправляем запрос
$wall = json_decode($wall); // Преобразуем JSON-строку в массив
$wall = $wall->response->items; // Получаем массив комментариев
for ($i = 0; $i < count($wall); $i++) {
    echo "<p><b>".($i + 1)."</b>. <i>".$wall[$i]->text."</i><br /><span>".date("m.d.Y", $wall[$i]->date)."</span></p>"; // Выводим записи
}
```

получаю записи, но никак не могу получить изображения со стены.

Comment: @baks1d, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Все просто, фотографии лежат в attachments. photo_75: содержит ссылку на изображение размерами 75х44.
Вообще ответ очень удобно посмотреть [здесь](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get).
Что касается идеи как доставать, то attachments это банальный JSONArray, в нем хранятся разные приложения к записи, в том числе и фото.